# What does “DM currencies” mean in this context?

Tags: investing, financial-literacy, terminology

"Key drivers include:

1. Low/negative real rates.
2. the view that the dollar has peaked against DM currencies
3. lingering macro risks."

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/ubs-note-on-golds-new-phase-after-brexit-2016-7

I googled it and the result is.... Deutsche Mark. It can't be like that, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I believe it means Developed Markets as opposed to Emerging Markets.](http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2013-08-24/news/41443933_1_rupiah-ems-vinay-khattar-mumbai)

> Asian debt markets have also been under pressure lately, reflecting
>   global asset reallocation from emerging markets (EMs) to developed
>   markets (DMs) in view of the growing unease over the impending
>   reversal in the QE stimulus by the US Fed.